# Uncaught TypeError: os.platform is not a function at credential-internal.js:38:20

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-admin

I'm creating a reusable library, im importing firebase admin sdk in my lib and calling my exported function inside my react app.

[image]

When ever i do `console.log(admin)` or try to use anything imported from 'firebase-admin',
Im getting weired errors.

[image]

Help me out. I am doing it in a correct approach.
what i really wanted is to create a reusable library based on **firebase** and **firebase-admin sdk**. My app is built with **NX Repo**.

Let me know how to fix it or what am i doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: What is `os`, based on the error, the problem seems to be this statement `console.log(os.platform())`, it seems that there is no `platform` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use firebase-admin directly in a React app, or any other frontend framework.  The JavaScript SDK requires a nodejs backend because it's used to perform privileged operations on your project that would be insecure to expose to your frontend.

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) makes this fairly clear:

> Add the Firebase Admin SDK to your server
>
> The Admin SDK is a set of server libraries that lets you interact with Firebase from privileged environments to perform actions like:

The way you're supposed to the the admin SDK in a web application is by having your app invoke a backend endpoint to perform the work on the user's behalf.